How to Instantly Move a Robot in Gazebo and RViz?
I'm looking for a way to instantly move a robot, spawned by 'robot_state_publisher', to a different location in both Gazebo and RViz.
Environment:

Ubuntu 22.04
ROS2 Humble
Gazebo 11.0.2 (classic)
RViz

Attempts and Findings:

Using a direct ROS2 service or API like SetPose()

No such service exists in the current environment.


Writing a Gazebo plugin using the SetModelState service

This service doesn't appear in the current setup any more ($ ros2 service list | grep gazebo does not list set_model_state or things like that).


Deleting and restarting the robot with a new pose

While deletion works ($ ros2 service call /delete_entity gazebo_msgs/srv/DeleteEntity "{name: 'my_robot'}"), it only removes the entity from Gazebo. RViz continues to visualize the robot because robot_state_publisher is still running. But 'robot_state_publisher' seems not to be one of the ROS2 lifecycle nodes, so cannot be stopped.



Any advice or alternative methods to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!
